# How to call a MSSQL Stored Procedure using Sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I am struggling with calling a MS SQL Stored Proc using Sequelize. This is how i normally call the stored proc from SSMS

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

DECLARE    @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetThings_ByLocation]
        @BeginDate = N'2016-06-23',
        @EndDate = N'2016-07-09',
        @LocationID = NULL

SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

How would i make this call using sequelize?

Comment: Please see my question and simplified answer on stackoverflow below. It is not necessary to format the parameters as you can use the replacements functionality. [Sequelize Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538525/sequelize-sytax-for-calling-stored-procedure-with-input-parameters-using-mssql/42538850#42538850)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sequelize uses npm package Tedious (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious) to work with MS SQL. Connecting to the database is the same as others.

You can use raw query to get results from stored procedures.

```
sequelize.query('GetThings_ByLocation @BeginDate=\'2016-08-01\', @EndDate=\'2016-08-07\', @LocationID=NULL;')
  .then(function(result) {
      console.log('RESULT', result);
  })
  .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Using .spread(function(result){.... instead of .then(function(result){...... would be a better option