# How to use stored procedure is sequalize orm

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures, orm, sequelize.js

I am using a stack of node, mssql, express for api generation, so how can we use an ORM like sequalize for mssql with stored procedure, is there way to use this or any documentation  related to this.

Right now I am using npm mssq with stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize uses npm package Tedious (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious) to work with MS SQL. Connecting to the database is the same as others.

You can use raw query to get results from stored procedures.
[the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384801/how-to-call-a-mssql-stored-procedure-using-sequelize)